# Tailwind: how to apply invert on dark mode i.e. dark:invert

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-ui

I need to invert the color when the mode is dark.
When I try to apply `dark:invert` I get the below error

```
./src/styles/input.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/styles/input.css)
Syntax error: The `dark:invert` class does not exist, but `2xl:invert` does. If you're sure that `dark:invert` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree. (2:10)


  1 | input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
> 2 |   @apply dark:invert;
    |          ^
  3 | }
```

Comment: Are you using version 3 of Tailwind? If you're still on version 2, you need to enable dark mode (https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode).

Comment: Were you able to find any resolution? It does not work for me either